# Prove that a set having $n\geq 2$ elements has $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ subsets having exactly two elements.

Tags: proof-writing, induction

I want to prove this by induction. I have everything up to proving $k+1$. I know I want to show that a set having $k+1$ elements has $\frac{k(k+1)}{2}$ but I'm struggling to find the beginning step for this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The hypothesis $n\geq 2$ is not required. All that is required is $n\geq 0$ (just plug it in and see).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to use the induction hypothesis, you can think about isolating an element, name it $a$, in your set, call it $E$, containing $k+1$ elements.

Then $E\setminus\{a\}$ has, by the induction hypothesis, $\frac{k(k-1)}2$ subsets having exactly two elements, and you must add the number of subsets of $E$ having two elements, one of which is $a$. There are $k$ such subsets. All in all, the number of subsets of $E$ having exactly two elements is:
$$\frac{k(k-1)}2+k=\frac{(k+1)k}2$$
which is what we wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Let S be a set with $n \ge 2$ elements. Say $S=\{s_1, \; ...\; s_n\}$ for some distinct $s_1, \; ...\; s_n$, then the subsets of S with precisely 2 elements are all sets of the form $\{s_i, s_j\} \; \forall 1\le i,j \le n $ such that $i\ne j$.

Now, fix j=1 and let i range from 2 to n. This gives (n-1) distinct subsets of S.

Next, fix j=2. Since $\{s_1, s_2\}=\{s_2, s_1\}$, a subset from the case j=1, we let i range from 3 to n this time, giving us (n-2) more distinct subsets of S.

Fix j=3, then $\{s_1, s_3\}=\{s_3, s_1\}, \{s_2, s_3\}=\{s_3, s_2\}$, which are the subsets from the previous two cases. Hence, we let i range from 4 to n to obtain still (n-3) more subsets of S.

Repeating the process (one may also use induction on j to present a more rigorous proof here), one finds that for each 
$1\le j \le n$, there are (n-j) distinct subsets of S in the form $\{s_i, s_j\}$ , where  i=j+1,  ... , n. Moreover, the subsets found in the case for different choices of j are also all distinct from each other.

Therefore the number of the desired subsets is 
$$\sum_{j=1}^{n} n-j = \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} j = \frac{n(n-1)}{2}$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: What is the meaning of the following binomial $\binom{n}{2}$?

Comment: The question is tagged as induction, so that's not very helpful...